# Adding entry to route table with CDK (typescript) when its private subnet already exists

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

Is it possible to add an entry to an imported private subnet's route table with CDK in typescript? I'm importing the VPC with:

```
import ec2 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-ec2');
vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(...)
```

(docs on `fromVpcAttributes`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.Vpc.html#static-from-wbr-vpc-wbr-attributesscope-id-attrs), and its private subnets are therefore being imported as an array of `ISubnet`s. I want to set up VPC Peering targets/destinations in each of these private subnets' route tables, and the most common way to do this seems to be via the `Subnet`'s `addRoute` method (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.Subnet.html#add-wbr-routeid-options). This works when the subnets are newly made, such as here: https://qiita.com/is_ryo/items/66dfe6c4b6dda4bd1eeb, but my private subnets don't have this method, since they were imported as `ISubnet`s. Is there a way to import these subnets as Subnets instead? Or, a better way to add entries in this case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I actually got stuck in a similar situation today, which I was able to solve by instantiating new CloudFormation `Route` resources:

```
vpc.privateSubnets.forEach(({ routeTable: { routeTableId } }, index) => {
  new CfnRoute(stack, 'PrivateSubnetPeeringConnectionRoute' + index, {
    destinationCidrBlock: '10.0.0.0/16',
    routeTableId,
    vpcPeeringConnectionId: peeringConnection.ref,
  })
})
```

You will need to know the ID of the peering connection for those routes. In the example above, it's referenced as it's created in the same stack:

```
const peeringConnection = new CfnVPCPeeringConnection(
  stack,
  'PeeringConnection',
  {
    peerVpcId: peerVpc.vpcId,
    vpcId: vpc.vpcId,
  }
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! This solution works out for me too.